# Visualforce - Overriding "Save" button behavior

Tags: visualforce

Currently in my VF Page (inline editing support enabled) after clicking "Save" button, I am being taken to the default detail page layout.

I want "Save" operation to be executed upon clicking the "Save" button but make the user stay on the same page.

Can someone tell what should I do ?

My Code :

```
<apex:page standardcontroller="Expense__c" sidebar="false" showHeader="true" showChat="false"  >
<apex:form >

<apex:inlineEditSupport />
<apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="Save" id="theButton"/>
<apex:pageBlock title="List of Expenses">
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!Expense__c}" var="item" >
<apex:column value="{!item.Date__c}"/>

<apex:column value="{!item.Type__c}"/>
<apex:column value="{!item.Amount__c}"/>
<apex:column value="{!item.Comments__c}"/>
</apex:pageBlockTable>
</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Have you overridden the buttons in the salesforce configuration on the object?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like your page invokes the standard controller's default `save` method that returns the default detail page URL. To change that URL you can write your own `save` method that first invokes the standard controller's `save` to do most of the work and then returns a page URL of your choosing:

```
public with sharing class ExpenseController {
    private ApexPages.StandardController sc;
    public ExpenseController(ApexPages.StandardController sc) {
        this.sc = sc;
    }
    public PageReference save() {
        PageReference detailPage = sc.save();
        if (detailPage != null) {
            // Construct URL of edit page or whatever other page you want
            PageReference editPage = new PageReference(detailPage.getUrl() + '/e');
            return editPage;
        } else {
            return detailPage;
        }
    }
}
```

Include the name of the controller extension in the page:

```
<apex:page standardcontroller="Expense__c" extensions="ExpenseController" ...
```

Comment: Is it possible to have the quicksave function in the above code? That would be very handy too..

Comment: @MnZ The standard controller has a `quickSave` method you can invoke from an extra "Quick Save" button.